# Outputting global variables

Tags: php, global-variables

I'm trying to use global variable across a class.

Basically, the function `render($html, $pageTitle);` is called.

Within that class, exists functions such as `buildHeader($pageTitle)` which looks like this:

```
private static function addHeader($pageTitle){
    global $pageTitle;
    $html = self::capture_output('header.inc');
    return $html;
}
```

within header.inc, I define the variable `$pageTitle` as global, however, it's not echoing the variable.

I'm also not getting errors that the variable has not been defined / initialised.

the `render` function calls the private methods, such as `addHeader` to build the page content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cover $pageTitle by function argument. Also you should rather use `$_GLOBALS['pageTitle'];` instead of using `global` which makes code more clear and helps avoid such conflicts you have. also, I quite believe you should rather move your `global $pageTitle;` to `capture_output()` function, where it seem to be used, instead of keeping it in `addHeader()` where it got no effect.